# Module not found in pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

When I try to run pyinstaller this shows.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib'

I'm trying to my code with gui into a .exe so that other people can use it without any need for an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyinstaller-hooks-contrib
```

I don't know your scenario but you can try Installing the package pyinstaller-hooks-contrib using pip.